# Unable to connect to internet from Centos VM

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-interface

I am using VirtualBox 4.3, I have installed centos 6.3. I have two adpaters attached.

1) NAT

2) Host-Only

I want to be able to setup a cluster of 3 machines which can talk to each other and also be able to connect to the internet. However, When I just used NAT with dhcp on to test connectivity to internet, It was working fine. But when i have added Host-only adapter and set up static IP on it, The internet connection got messed up. Please, help me if i am doing anything wrong.

config files that i have changed

NAT Adapter

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
[image]

Host-Only Adapter

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

[image]

When I have turned off IPtables and disabled selinux. When i try to ping www.google.com I am getting unknown host

I have tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf and also DNS to eth0 (as "DNS", "DNS0").

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `GATEWAY` line for the NAT adapter.

I'd also recommend that you use Bridged for the Internet adapter. It creates a lot fewer problems. I would only use NAT for a guest OS that didn't have effective inbound security, so I wanted to rely on the host OS's firewall and such.

Once you do that, you won't need the host-only adapter. The bridged guest OSes will be able to see each other then, for the same reason normal hosts on your LAN can see each other. In general, you only want to use host-only networking when creating a VM that will *only* talk to the host OS, or to other VMs. (e.g. A test VM that gets set up once and then *never* updated.) Once you decide to let the VMs see out to the wider network, it really isn't doing anything useful for you.